# NodeJs / Sequelize - Setting default value of a column same as ID on entry creation

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

Ok, so I am developing an ECommerce API with different products and categories. Categories may have a parent_category. For example, I could have "shoes" as a general category, and the I could have other category such as "fancy shoes", which could have "shoes" as its parent category.

I have both id and parent_category_id in my model, with the corresponding association to make a self join.

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const alias = 'ProductCategory';
  const cols = {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
      primaryKey: true,
      allowNull: false,
      autoIncrement: true,
    },
    uuid: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      unique: true,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    parent_category_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
      allowNull: false,
    },
    category_name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(255),
      allowNull: false,
    },

    is_active: {
      type: DataTypes.TINYINT(4),
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: 0,
    },
  };

  const config = {
    tableName: 'product_category',
    timestamps: 'true',
    createdAt: 'inserted_at',
    updatedAt: 'updated_at',
  };

  const ProductCategory = sequelize.define(alias, cols, config);

  ProductCategory.associate = (models) => {
    ProductCategory.hasMany(models.ProductCategory, {
      as: 'product_category',
      foreignKey: 'parent_category_id',
    });

    ProductCategory.belongsTo(models.ProductCategory, {
      as: 'product_category_parent',
      foreignKey: 'parent_category_id',
    });

  return ProductCategory;
};
```

I would like to be able to set the default value of `parent_category_id` to equal the `id` in case I don´t send a different value on creation. I have managed to make this work on the controller by first creating the entry, and then updating it in case I have got a different value of `parent_category_id` in the request body.

```
const categoriesPost = async (req, res = response) => {
  try {
    const { parent_category_id, category_name } = req.body;

    const category = await db.ProductCategory.create({
      parent_category_id: 1,
      category_name,
      uuid: uuidv4(),
    });

    await db.ProductCategory.update(
      {
        parent_category_id: parent_category_id
          ? parent_category_id
          : category.id,
      },
      { where: { id: category.id } }
    );

    res.status(200).json({msg: 'ok, entry created'});
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
```

I know this is very rudimentary but I have not been able to make this work other way around.

I have tried adding a defaultValue in the model like this to the `parent_category_id`

```
 parent_category_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: (sequelize.col('id')),
    },
```

But this obviously did not work

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: I never saw the assigment of the same record as parent one if it has no parent. What's the catch? It's much easier to leave it `null` in this case. That way you always know if a parentId is not null then there is a parent record.